# Subset a specific variable within a dataframe in a nested list

Tags: r

I have nested list that look something similar to

```
test <- list(a = list(a1 = 1:5, a2 = 6:10, a3=data.frame(a4 = letters, a5 = LETTERS)),
     b = list(a1 = 11:15, a2 = 16:20, a3=data.frame(a4 = letters, a5 = LETTERS)))
```

I am interested in extracting vector a5 (probably as a list) for each data.frame. I know I can extract a specific element in the list (e.g. dataframe) using the following

```
a3 <- sapply(test, '[', 'a3')
```

but I am not sure how can I get a specific variable within the dataframe.

Update:
I also should add that I know I can use lapply in the result (e.g. `lapply(a3, '[', 'a5'`) to get the dataframe but I wonder if there is a shorter way.

Comment: `test[["a"]][["a3"]]$a5` or `test[["b"]][["a3"]]$a5` ? I don't understand what you mean by "shorter way".

Comment: I guess is there a function to entirely subset based on the name independently of the structure?

Answer (score 2):

You might try `list.select` from [`rlist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/index.html)

```
library(rlist)
list.select(test, a3$a5)
#$a
#$a[[1]]
# [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
#
#
#$b
#$b[[1]]
# [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

---

Another option using `lapply`

```
lapply(test, function(x) {
  x$a3$a5
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(test, ~ pluck(.x$a3, "a5"))
#$a
# [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

#$b
# [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```